# Blockchain takes abnormally long to synchronise?

Tags: blockchain, mist, wallets, synchronization, fast-sync

I recently formatted my computer, re-installed Ubuntu and consequently have to re-download and re-synchronise the blockchain. I initially started using the most recent (as of this posting) Mist release and left it overnight; progressed around 1.8M blocks. The following day, I moved this data to a backup folder and restarted entirely using `geth --fast --cache=1024`. 24 hours later this had advanced 2.8M blocks. I have now gone back to Mist and continued from the 2.8M, but it is moving incredibly slow to the point where I am convinced I am missing something..? Any suggestions would be much appreciated! I should add that I am running on a 1GBit connection, so that, if anything, is definitely not the bottleneck.

Comment: I wanted to follow up; 18 hours later I have downloaded an additional ~500K blocks and recent surpassed 3.3M. It is very frequently losing peers and otherwise downloading slow throughout. I do not recall it being this bad by any means whatsoever the other times I have synced.

Comment: If in your logs appear a lots of "Imported new chain segment" it is likely geth switched from fast to normal. In those cases you can try restart your sync from the beginning. Follow this indications https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17306. It can be caused by bad connections between nodes.