# When Geth fast is sync, it starts over from 0

Tags: go-ethereum

After 2 days of `geth --fast`, 
Geth was able to reach the latest 38xxxxx blocks:

..and suddenly it seems it's automatically leaving the fast sync and starting over slowly from block 0.

Here is the full output of the transition  :

```
[....]
INFO [06-06|08:48:37] Imported new block receipts              count=4    elapsed=71.004ms   number=3812433 hash=b56f11.4a4a62 ignored=0
INFO [06-06|08:48:37] Imported new state entries               count=1    elapsed=4.000ms    processed=7925815 pending=2833
INFO [06-06|08:48:37] Imported new state entries               count=5    elapsed=19.001ms   processed=7925820 pending=2903
INFO [06-06|08:48:38] Imported new state entries               count=6    elapsed=39.002ms   processed=7925826 pending=2993
INFO [06-06|08:48:38] Imported new state entries               count=1    elapsed=9.000ms    processed=7925827 pending=3005
INFO [06-06|08:48:38] Imported new block receipts              count=5    elapsed=118.006ms  number=3812438 hash=74bacd.b07409 ignored=0
INFO [06-06|08:48:38] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=9.000ms    processed=7925829 pending=3037
INFO [06-06|08:48:39] Imported new state entries               count=3    elapsed=273.015ms  processed=7925832 pending=3079
INFO [06-06|08:48:39] Imported new state entries               count=8    elapsed=44.002ms   processed=7925840 pending=3190
INFO [06-06|08:48:39] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=28.001ms   processed=7925842 pending=3217
INFO [06-06|08:48:39] Imported new state entries               count=3    elapsed=28.001ms   processed=7925845 pending=3261
INFO [06-06|08:48:39] Imported new state entries               count=9    elapsed=37.002ms   processed=7925854 pending=3382
INFO [06-06|08:48:40] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=14.000ms   processed=7925856 pending=3454
INFO [06-06|08:48:40] Imported new state entries               count=3    elapsed=469.026ms  processed=7925859 pending=3454
INFO [06-06|08:48:40] Imported new state entries               count=6    elapsed=25.001ms   processed=7925865 pending=3538
INFO [06-06|08:48:40] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=26.001ms   processed=7925867 pending=3571
INFO [06-06|08:48:41] Imported new state entries               count=3    elapsed=30.001ms   processed=7925870 pending=3614
INFO [06-06|08:48:41] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=29.001ms   processed=7925872 pending=3643
INFO [06-06|08:48:41] Imported new state entries               count=3    elapsed=33.001ms   processed=7925875 pending=3681
INFO [06-06|08:48:41] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=11.000ms   processed=7925877 pending=3711
INFO [06-06|08:48:41] Imported new state entries               count=6    elapsed=253.014ms  processed=7925883 pending=3798
INFO [06-06|08:48:42] Imported new state entries               count=11   elapsed=67.003ms   processed=7925894 pending=3956
INFO [06-06|08:48:42] Imported new state entries               count=7    elapsed=43.002ms   processed=7925901 pending=4083
INFO [06-06|08:48:42] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=36.002ms   processed=7925903 pending=4083
INFO [06-06|08:48:42] Imported new state entries               count=8    elapsed=36.002ms   processed=7925911 pending=4189
INFO [06-06|08:48:45] Imported new block receipts              count=240  elapsed=2.977s     number=3812678 hash=2d31a6.083294 ignored=0
INFO [06-06|08:48:45] Imported new state entries               count=4    elapsed=45.002ms   processed=7925915 pending=4245
INFO [06-06|08:48:45] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=2.900s     processed=7925917 pending=4245
INFO [06-06|08:48:49] Imported new block receipts              count=367  elapsed=3.568s     number=3813045 hash=3e006c.4f33fb ignored=0
INFO [06-06|08:48:53] Imported new state entries               count=11   elapsed=7.615s     processed=7925928 pending=4303
INFO [06-06|08:48:53] Imported new state entries               count=1    elapsed=7.804s     processed=7925929 pending=4302
INFO [06-06|08:48:53] Imported new state entries               count=10   elapsed=397.022ms  processed=7925939 pending=4458
INFO [06-06|08:48:56] Imported new state entries               count=3    elapsed=56.003ms   processed=7925942 pending=4506
INFO [06-06|08:49:00] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=1.479s     processed=7925944 pending=4516
INFO [06-06|08:49:00] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=10.000ms   processed=7925946 pending=4541
INFO [06-06|08:49:00] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=4.204s     processed=7925948 pending=4541
INFO [06-06|08:49:00] Imported new state entries               count=1    elapsed=3.039s     processed=7925949 pending=4541
INFO [06-06|08:49:00] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=7.024s     processed=7925951 pending=4541
INFO [06-06|08:49:00] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=2.731s     processed=7925953 pending=4541
INFO [06-06|08:49:00] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=5.603s     processed=7925955 pending=4541
INFO [06-06|08:49:06] Imported new state entries               count=3    elapsed=15.000ms   processed=7925958 pending=4647
INFO [06-06|08:49:18] Imported new state entries               count=12   elapsed=6.305s     processed=7925970 pending=4699
INFO [06-06|08:49:18] Imported new state entries               count=1    elapsed=376.021ms  processed=7925971 pending=4703
INFO [06-06|08:49:18] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=11.986s    processed=7925973 pending=4703
INFO [06-06|08:49:18] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=10.419s    processed=7925975 pending=4703
WARN [06-06|08:49:18] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state data download canceled (requested)"
INFO [06-06|08:49:18] Imported new state entries               count=1    elapsed=8.985s     processed=7925976 pending=4703
INFO [06-06|08:49:18] Imported new state entries               count=2    elapsed=8.616s     processed=7925978 pending=4703
INFO [06-06|08:49:18] Imported new state entries               count=13   elapsed=17.648s    processed=7925991 pending=4703
WARN [06-06|08:49:24] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=638635ba553486c4 err=timeout
WARN [06-06|08:49:30] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="block download canceled (requested)"
INFO [06-06|08:49:39] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=198.011ms  mgasps=0.000 number=2       hash=b495a1.4698c9
INFO [06-06|08:49:45] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0   percentage=83 elapsed=3.194s
INFO [06-06|08:49:45] Generated ethash verification cache      epoch=0   elapsed=3.850s
INFO [06-06|08:49:46] Imported new chain segment               blocks=4 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=4.168s     mgasps=0.000 number=6       hash=1f1aed.6b326e
WARN [06-06|08:49:46] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=b5b6525a9debd11c err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
INFO [06-06|08:49:51] Imported new chain segment               blocks=30 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=1.400s     mgasps=0.000 number=36      hash=5f81bf.8cbf9a
INFO [06-06|08:49:53] Imported new chain segment               blocks=29 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=1.223s     mgasps=0.000 number=65      hash=35209c.d130dd
INFO [06-06|08:49:53] Imported new chain segment               blocks=17 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=872.049ms  mgasps=0.000 number=82      hash=861461.3f3d8c
INFO [06-06|08:49:58] Imported new chain segment               blocks=82 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=4.328s     mgasps=0.000 number=164     hash=cc7fe7.0c1e01
INFO [06-06|08:50:06] Imported new chain segment               blocks=191 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.374s     mgasps=0.000 number=355     hash=6cb52d.258937
INFO [06-06|08:50:14] Imported new chain segment               blocks=222 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.025s     mgasps=0.000 number=577     hash=c4cee3.93da3f
INFO [06-06|08:50:23] Imported new chain segment               blocks=251 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.199s     mgasps=0.000 number=828     hash=b00a2e.5b092a
INFO [06-06|08:50:31] Imported new chain segment               blocks=130 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.080s     mgasps=0.000 number=958     hash=0dde79.341549
INFO [06-06|08:50:39] Imported new chain segment               blocks=181 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.082s     mgasps=0.000 number=1139    hash=b4a358.d27eba
INFO [06-06|08:50:47] Imported new chain segment               blocks=181 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.021s     mgasps=0.000 number=1320    hash=284ae7.ac5c92
INFO [06-06|08:50:51] Imported new chain segment               blocks=114 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=4.376s     mgasps=0.000 number=1434    hash=943b83.6e9a56
INFO [06-06|08:50:59] Imported new chain segment               blocks=216 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.001s     mgasps=0.000 number=1650    hash=4d5d49.7b09af
INFO [06-06|08:51:07] Imported new chain segment               blocks=203 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.030s     mgasps=0.000 number=1853    hash=60cfd1.ba336a
INFO [06-06|08:51:15] Imported new chain segment               blocks=163 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.046s     mgasps=0.000 number=2016    hash=80ca4e.018305
INFO [06-06|08:51:23] Imported new chain segment               blocks=160 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.002s     mgasps=0.000 number=2176    hash=725d27.0971e2
INFO [06-06|08:51:31] Imported new chain segment               blocks=189 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.028s     mgasps=0.000 number=2365    hash=c4b0a2.713532
INFO [06-06|08:51:39] Imported new chain segment               blocks=220 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.009s     mgasps=0.000 number=2585    hash=e0d04a.526335
INFO [06-06|08:51:47] Imported new chain segment               blocks=219 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.011s     mgasps=0.000 number=2804    hash=6765e1.91b5d8
INFO [06-06|08:51:56] Imported new chain segment               blocks=253 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.201s     mgasps=0.000 number=3057    hash=2c8e6e.ab2f85
INFO [06-06|08:52:04] Imported new chain segment               blocks=280 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.011s     mgasps=0.000 number=3337    hash=e99d17.637e30
INFO [06-06|08:52:07] Imported new chain segment               blocks=145 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=3.431s     mgasps=0.000 number=3482    hash=6c29c0.e46a2a
INFO [06-06|08:52:15] Imported new chain segment               blocks=347 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.021s     mgasps=0.000 number=3829    hash=8226c6.a3e01a
[....]
```

Am I missing something? 
"Imported new chain segment" is progressing so slowly. it will take weeks to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the synchronization has failed (and maybe it will fail in the next sync), try to update your geth then try to use :

```
geth removedb

geth upgradedb
```

then wait for the chain to resync.

Comment: thanks,
I have upgraded to 1.6.5  (I think I was on ~1.6.1)
I have entered the 2 commands.... now I'm assuming I'll have to wait 2 more days to know if sync is success.
no way to know a fail before the end of sync ?

Comment: unfortunatly no way to do so, you could maybe use geth --light or --fast instead synching the full chain.

Comment: How do you know it has failed? I see no message that indicates a failure.

Comment: The highest log level is [WARN]